# Can not style Laravel mail with queues

Tags: laravel, email, queue

when I send mail with queue and want to customize css for markdown mails it does not work, everything works correct without queues, is that known issue?

when I have

```
Mail::to('fsafs@gmail.com')->send(new RoleUpdatedMail($admin));
```

it works and uses `custom.css` located in `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/custom.css`

if I change to

```
Mail::to('fsafs@gmail.com')->queue(new RoleUpdatedMail($admin));
```

it resorts to default.css in vendor directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks u/Nathan from discord

> could it be that the queue process needs to be reloaded queue:work
> will cache the code, so changes to it won't be picked up. try stopping
> / starting the process or use queue:listen . See if that makes a diff
> https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#the-queue-work-command
>
> Remember, queue workers, are long-lived processes and store the booted
> application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes
> in your code base after they have been started. So, during your
> deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers. In
> addition, remember that any static state created or modified by your
> application will not be automatically reset between jobs.

Comment: This should have been a comment given it is a complement